# How to change oscillator frequency?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I started to experiment with the **Web Audio API**, trying to create different oscillators to produce acoustic waves.

Since I'm kinda new to the whole process, I'm wondering if there's a way to play tones, not with a constant frequency, but changing them midways.

***Example:***
I want a tone, that starts at **300 Hz** for **3 seconds**, and then **raise linearly** to **400 Hz** over the next **4 seconds**.

I fount this, but I'm not really sure if it is what I'm looking for:

```
osc.setPeriodicWave(wave);
```

My JavaScript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Function that plays the tone.
var playTone = function(duration, frequency) {
var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var osc = context.createOscillator(); 
// Sine is the default type. Also available: square, sawtooth and triangle waveforms.
osc.type = 'sine'; 
// Frequency in Hz.
osc.frequency.value = frequency; // Frequency in Hz
osc.connect(context.destination); 
osc.start(context.currentTime);
osc.stop(context.currentTime + duration);
}

// Button and input functionality.
$("button").on("click", function() {

var whichButton = $(this).text()
var duration = document.getElementById("durationInput").value;
var frequency = document.getElementById("f1Input").value;
if (whichButton == "  Play") {
  playTone(duration, frequency); 
}

});

});
```

*My codepen with the work so far:*  [Codepen.io - Acoustic wave generator](http://codepen.io/KonSal/pen/PGLEvK?editors=1010)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third party site.

Comment: Done as requested! Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a PeriodicWave - that's for harmonic (additive) synthesis.

This is pretty straightforward - you just need to use the frequency AudioParam's scheduling methods "setValueAtTime" and "linearRampToValueAtTime".  Try this:

```
// Function that plays the tone.
var playTone = function(duration, frequency) {
    var context = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var osc = context.createOscillator(); 
    // Sine is the default type. Also available: square, sawtooth and triangle waveforms.
    osc.type = 'sine'; 
    var now = context.currentTime;
    // Frequency in Hz.
    // Set initial value. (you can use .value=freq if you want)
    osc.frequency.setValueAtTime(frequency, now);
    // set a "checkpoint" in 3 seconds - that will be the starting point of the ramp.
    osc.frequency.setValueAtTime(frequency, now+3);
    // set a ramp to freq+100Hz over the next 4 seconds.
    osc.frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(frequency+100,now+7)
    osc.connect(context.destination); 
    osc.start(now);
    osc.stop(now + duration);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info and the help! It is behaving strange though. **Lowering the frequency is working great**, but if I try to raise the frequency (in my example for **3 < time < 7 seconds**, it would play the original tone for the first 3 seconds and then it will produce a **high pitch for like 0.5 sec and stop**.

Comment: Provide a minimal example of this problem; without seeing it, it's really hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: Apparently, if I get rid of jQuery, .linearRampToValueAtTime works fine, either raising or lowering the frequency. Something's wrong about the jQuery that destroys the raise of the frequency, using @cwilso 's code.

Comment: Ha!  The problem you're having is that both frequency and difference are STRINGS, not numbers - and the evaluation of "linearRampToValueAtTime(frequency + difference..." is causing problems, because if I set freq=440 and diff=10, it's getting "440"+"10"="44010".  You need to call parseFloat() on those - e.g. "linearRampToValueAtTime(parseFloat(frequency) + parseFloat(difference)...", should fix it right up.