# How to fast change frequency of played tone without crackling?

Tags: javascript, loops, audio, synthesizer

I have loop at 50-200FPS and want to visualise data with sound. I need fast and **smooth** respond to data changing, like Therminvox.
What library and approach is best for this?

Issues with simpleTones.js:

- sound degrade over ~2min and finally stopped working
- i don't find how to change frequency, but not only play separate notes

Issues with Tone.js:

- i don't find how to change frequency

```js
document.onmousemove=init
bInit=false;
Timeout=100;
NoteLength=100;
function init() //this is not solving alert "The AudioContext was not allowed to start"
{
    if(bInit) return;
    //const osc = new Tone.Oscillator(440, "sine").toDestination().start();
    setTimeout(loop, 200);
    bInit=true;
}
function freqRand(){return 50+Math.random()*1000;}

function loop( )
{
    playTone(freqRand(),'sine',NoteLength/1000)
    setTimeout(loop, Timeout);
}


//--------UI
function sliderTimeout_change(v){
    Timeout=v; document.getElementById('Timeout').innerText=v;
}
function sliderNoteLength_change(v){
    NoteLength=v; document.getElementById('NoteLength').innerText=v;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/escottalexander/simpleTones.js/simpleTones.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="Tone.js"></script>  -->
<body>
Timeout = <i id='Timeout'></i><br>
<input id='sliderTimeout' type="range" min="10" max="200" value="100" oninput="sliderTimeout_change(this.value)"><br><br>
NoteLength = <i id='NoteLength'></i><br>
<input id='sliderNoteLength' type="range" min="10" max="4000" value="100" oninput="sliderNoteLength_change(this.value)">
</body>
```

Comment: I would avoid using any library to synthesize your audio ...  start by creating a loop to play a simple sin curve at a set frequency ... get that working ... then come up with an algorithm to transform your data stream into a series of points on a curve which wobbles inside the audio frequency range say 300 to 3000 Hertz ...  always healthy to get out of the self limiting assumption a library will solve any challenge and into the freedom you gain by doing all that heavy lifting in your own code

Comment: Do you think filling some buffer manually would be better than this technique: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291462/changing-oscillator-frequency   I have tried playing buffers with NAudio C#  and it has bad performance related to latency, buffer swap and crackling

Comment: you should be able to get the answer in that link up and running which will render audio output ... its using Web Audio API which is a great feature baked into all browsers ... your secret sauce will be how to translate your arbitrary data into a sequence of freq shifts ( up or down ) to drive calls to that api ...  big question is is your process real time ?   must the desired output audio be in sync with your input data stream ?  as your data varies should that drive a mirroring of varying freq ? or varying volume

Comment: linearRampToValueAtTime working good. But for testing Buffer I cant find any examples of how to update or swap bufffer to continuous playing. They all shows how to createBuffer, fill and singe play , like http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/JavaScript.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer.html

Comment: Easy to do in Java, but IDK if JavaScript has the same capabilities. If you can create a data array of a tone's PCM data (for example, an A=440 Hz) and use it as a streaming, looping data source via JavaScript, I can show you some nifty interpolation tricks to change the pitch smoothly and in real time, including smoothing out the loop point if there is a discontinuity there (creating a click). Linear interpolation is the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task solved with next code, using builtin linearRampToValueAtTime but it is better to have addition exaple of how to do this with Buffer.

```js
document.onclick=init //onmousemove is not solving alert "The AudioContext was not allowed to start"
bInit=false;
Timeout=100;
var osc;
var aContext;
function init()
{
    if(bInit) return;
    
    aContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    osc = aContext.createOscillator(); 
    osc.type = 'sine';  //sine square sawtooth triangle 
    var now = aContext.currentTime;
    osc.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, now);
    osc.connect(aContext.destination); 
    osc.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, now+1);
    osc.start(now);
    
    setTimeout(loop, 100);

    bInit=true;
}
function loop( )
{
    let freq=freqRand(); freq=smothFrequency(freq);
    
    osc.frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(freq,aContext.currentTime+Timeout/1000)
    
    setTimeout(loop, Timeout);
}

function freqRand(){return 300+Math.random()*300+ Math.sin(aContext.currentTime/10)*250;}

//============================== end of main part, next is for playing
//--------signal conditioning, smooth
var freq_avg=0;
var freq_avg_k=0.1;
var freq_RangeMul=1;

function smothFrequency(freq_new)
{
    freq_new*=freq_RangeMul;
    if(freq_avg==0 || bNoSmooth) freq_avg=freq_new;
    else //smooth freq change
    {
        if(Math.abs(freq_avg-freq_new)<Timeout/4) // no smooth when changes 4hz/ms
                freq_avg=freq_avg;
        else 
        {
            if(Timeout>50) //less smooth for long timeout, or 'sharp'
            {
                freq_avg=freq_avg*(1-freq_avg_k*4)+freq_new*freq_avg_k*4;
                if(freq_avg_k>=0.25)
                {
                    if(bSharpKeepRange)
                    {
                        if(freq_avg<0) freq_avg=-freq_avg;
                        if(freq_avg>1600) freq_RangeMul/=1.05
                        else if(freq_avg<40) freq_RangeMul*=1.05
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                freq_avg=freq_avg*(1-freq_avg_k)+freq_new*freq_avg_k; 
        }
    }
    //console.log(aContext.currentTime, freq, freq_RangeMul);
    return freq_avg;
}

//--------UI
var cc=null
function sliderTimeout_change(v){
    cc=v;
    v=v.value
    Timeout=v; document.getElementById('Timeout').innerText=v;
}
function sliderNoteLength_change(v){
    NoteLength=v; document.getElementById('NoteLength').innerText=v;
}
bNoSmooth=false;
function sliderfreq_avg_k_change(v){
    freq_avg_k=v/1000; 
    bNoSmooth=(freq_avg_k>0.22 && freq_avg_k<0.33);
    let str=freq_avg_k;
    if(bNoSmooth)str='no smooth';
    if(freq_avg_k>0.33)
    {
        document.getElementById('bSharpKeepRange').style.display='block';
        str=str+' sharp';
    }
    else document.getElementById('bSharpKeepRange').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('freq_avg_k').innerText=str;
}
function checkbox_bSharpKeepRange_click(checkbox)
{
  bSharpKeepRange=checkbox.checked
   freq_avg=100;
   freq_RangeMul=1;
}
bSharpKeepRange=false;
```

```html
<body>
Timeout ms = <i id='Timeout'></i><br>
<input id='sliderTimeout' type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="10" oninput="sliderTimeout_change(this)"><br><br>
freq change smooth factor = <i id='freq_avg_k'></i><br>
<input id='sliderfreq_avg_k' type="range" min="2" max="550" value="10" oninput="sliderfreq_avg_k_change(this.value)"><br>
<i id="bSharpKeepRange">
keep range 
 <input id='checkbox_bSharpKeepRange' type="checkbox" onclick='checkbox_bSharpKeepRange_click(this);'>
</i>
</body>
```